# Can geodatabase edits be canceled/modified with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, add-in

I am working on some tools to automate some field data collection.  I would like to restrict the user's ability to delete features (such as when the DELETE key is pressed, or if the MERGE editor tool is used), and instead populate a field with some attribute noting that it was 'deleted'.

I have looked at the [IEditEvents.OnDeleteFeature](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IEditEvents_OnDeleteFeature.htm) and [IObjectClassEvents.OnDelete](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IObjectClassEvents_OnDelete.htm) events, but there seems to be no built-in way to stop the action.

[Some have suggested that IEdtior.AbortOberation() be used](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcobjects-sdk-questions/how-to-stop-ondeletefeature/m-p/1188411#M20486), but this will cancel all edits made within the operation, not just the Deletes.  Is there a programmatic way in ArcObjects to cancel an edit event at the row level?

Answer (score 1):

I've hacked together a solution and will post it here as a workaround.  I'm hoping someone will chime in with a better approach.  The following approach catches deletes from pressing the delete key and when the Editor Merge tools is used.  I haven't tested too in depth with other editor tools.

First, some class level variables

```
private IEditor3 _editor;                 // grab reference in constructor
private IEditEvents2_Event _editEvents2;  // grab reference elsewhere
private IDifferenceCursorEx _diffCursorExUpdates;
private IDifferenceCursorEx _diffCursorExDeletes;
private IFeatureLayer _flWorkspace;       // layer of interest, grab reference elsewhere
```

Next, wire into two IEditEvents2_Event events.

```
if (_editEvents2 != null) {
    _editEvents2.BeforeStopOperation += Events_BeforeStopOperation;
    _editEvents2.OnAbort += Events_OnAbort;
}
```

The BeforeStopOperation method is fired just before edits are committed, giving us time to grab and keep what was changed, and then aborting the edit operation to revert all changes.  IDataChangesEX lets us retain what was changed, even after the edit operation is aborted.

```
void Events_BeforeStopOperation() {
    _diffCursorExDeletes = null;
    _diffCursorExUpdates = null;
    
    IWorkspaceEdit2 wsEdit2 = (IWorkspaceEdit2)_editor.EditWorkspace;
    IDataChangesEx dataChangesEx = wsEdit2.get_EditDataChanges(esriEditDataChangesType.esriEditDataChangesWithinOperation);
    IFIDSet fidSet = dataChangesEx.get_ChangedIDs("workspace", esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeDeleteNoChange);
    
    // check for deletes
    if (fidSet.Count() > 0) {             
        // we have deletes
        _diffCursorExDeletes = dataChangesEx.ExtractEx("workspace", esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeDeleteNoChange);         
        _diffCursorExUpdates = dataChangesEx.ExtractEx("workspace", esriDifferenceType.esriDifferenceTypeUpdateNoChange);
        
        // abort operation to revert all changes in current operation
        _editor.AbortOperation();                    
    }
}
```

The OnAbort event is fired only when an editor.AbortOperation() is used.  Since we forced an abort in the BeforeStopOperation(), we can check if any of our differentCursors are null and then process any changes inside a new edit operation.  I was concerned with edits to a particular featureclass, and didn't see a need to capture Inserts (yet).

```
void Events_OnAbort() {
    if (_diffCursorExDeletes != null) {
        try {
            // start new operation
            _editor.StartOperation();

            // set up empty variables
            IRow sourceRow, diffRow;
            ILongArray diffIndices;
            int oid = -1;

            // process deletes
            _diffCursorExDeletes.Next(out oid, out sourceRow, out diffRow, out diffIndices);
            while (oid != -1) {
                var feat = _flWorkspace.FeatureClass.GetFeature(oid);
                // instead of deleting the feature, we update a 'status' field
                int statusIdx = feat.Fields.FindField("status");
                if (statusIdx > -1) {
                    feat.set_Value(statusIdx, "DELETE");
                    feat.Store();
                }
                _diffCursorExDeletes.Next(out oid, out sourceRow, out diffRow, out diffIndices);
            }
            // process updates
            oid = -1;
            _diffCursorExUpdates.Next(out oid, out sourceRow, out diffRow, out diffIndices);
            while (oid != -1) {
                var feat = _flWorkspace.FeatureClass.GetFeature(oid);
                // Go to each changed field and swap the old and new values.
                for (int i = 0; i < diffIndices.Count; i++) {
                    // will throw an error if you try to update non-editable fields
                    if (feat.Fields.Field[diffIndices.get_Element(i)].Editable == false)
                        continue;
                    feat.set_Value(diffIndices.get_Element(i), sourceRow.get_Value(diffIndices.get_Element(i)));
                }
                feat.Store();
                _diffCursorExUpdates.Next(out oid, out sourceRow, out diffRow, out diffIndices);
            }
            // stop the operation, adding it to the edit stack               
            _editor.StopOperation("Prevent Deletes");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ERROR in OnAbort\n{0}", e.StackTrace));
            // null out variable so that subsequent abort does not result in endless loop
            _diffCursorExDeletes = null;
            _editor.AbortOperation();
        }

        // be sure to null this out when complete
        _diffCursorExDeletes = null;
    }
}
```